# Error mapping linear fit to scatter plot in ggplot: Mapping should be a list of unevaluated mappings created by aes or aes_string

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataset as follows:

> head(outputDF)
>       var1    var2             snpR stepD
>   1 A    B 1.55809163171629     6
>   2 A    C 1.57475543745267     6
>   3 A    D 1.36003481988361     4
>   4 A    E 1.60338829251054     4
>   5 A    F 1.54720598772132     5
>   6 B    C 1.10321616677002     2

I have a nice scatterplot from the function:

```
ggplot(outputDF, aes(x=as.numeric(as.character(snpR)), y=stepD)) +geom_point(shape=1) +
  xlab("SNP Distance") + ylab("Shortest Path Distance") +
  theme(axis.text=element_text(size=13),
        axis.title=element_text(size=13))
```

But now I am adding a best linear fit to the data. I have tried:

```
ggplot(outputDF, aes(x=as.numeric(as.character(snpR)), y=stepD)) +geom_point(shape=1) +
  xlab("SNP Distance") + ylab("Shortest Path Distance") +
  theme(axis.text=element_text(size=13),
        axis.title=element_text(size=13)) + 
  stat_smooth(outputDF, geom="smooth", method="lm", formula=stepD~snpR)
```

But this gives me the error:

```
Error in get(x, envir = this, inherits = inh)(this, ...) : 
  Mapping should be a list of unevaluated mappings created by aes or aes_string
```

The more I play with aes, the stranger my plot looks. What am I missing in my thinking?

Comment: Have you read the documentation at http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.3.1/stat_smooth.html? `+ stat_smooth(method = "lm", formula = stepD ~ snpR)` should do it

Comment: Thank you! That was something I tried, but I got the error "Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'stepD' not found"

Comment: actually you don't even need the formula, just try this `+stat_smooth(method="lm")` as the last line of your ggplot call

Comment: I did that too! At the very beginning....

Comment: It makes a separate horizontal line for each y-value best fitted to all of its x values!

Comment: I'm not sure if that is because the y-values are whole integers, and x values are not...

Comment: Look at `?stat_smooth` and pay close attention to the _order_ of the arguments, and then look at how you've passed your arguments.

Comment: I got it :o) I needed to do the as.numeric(as.character) for the y-values too. Thanks for your help...